# Solving a parametric limit using Taylor series

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Solve

$$ \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln   ( \cos^a x) + \sin^2 x}{\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{x^4}} = \frac{0}{0}= \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{a \ln   ( \cos x) + \sin^2 x}{\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{x^4}}$$

using Taylor series we can write :

- $\sin x =  x - \frac{1}{3}x^3 + o(x^3) \implies  \sin^2 x= x^2
     -\frac{2}{3}x^4 + o(x^4)$
- $\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2) \implies \ln(\cos x) = ( 1- x^2 +
     o(x^2) )  $

therefore the numerator will be $$ \alpha( 1- x^2 + o(x^2) + x^2 -\frac{2}{3}x^4 + o(x^4) ) = \alpha +x^2(1-\alpha )+o(x^2) $$

i have the following problem to keep going,   $\arctan (1/x^4) $,  the argument of the function tends to infinity therefore i don't know how to "solve" the zero at the denominator therefore i can't use taylor to solve the denominator, and if i can't use it at the denominator i also could not at the numerator because otherwise i will not be able to get rid of the $o(x^2)$, but without using the Taylor series i don't know if there's a way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use that

$$\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{x^4} =\arctan x^4=x^4+ o(x^4)$$

note also that for the numerator

- $\sin^2 x= x^2 -\frac{x^4 }{3}+ o(x^4)$
- $\ln(\cos x) = -\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^4}{12}+ o(x^4)$

Comment: why $ arctan\frac{1}{x^4} -\frac {\pi}{2} = arctan x^4 ?$

Comment: @MassimilianoMessina This is a foundamental identity, refer for example to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: I get that the limit for $a=2$ is -1/6 for $a>2$ is -∞ and for $a<2$ +∞ , but Wolfram alpha says that if $a=2$ the limit is -1/2, what have I done wrong? The $x⁴$ terms for $a=2$ are $2/12 -1/3=-1/6$

Comment: We need $a=2$ for the existence and for the $x^4$ terms in the numerator we obtain $-1/6-1/3=-1/2$ which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the point $(x^4, 1)$ in the Cartesian plane.  The triangle in the first quadrant with hypotenuse as the line segment from this point to the origin and right angle on the $x$-axis is such that the counterclockwise angle $\theta$ from the positive $x$-axis to the hypotenuse satisfies
$$\tan \theta = \frac{1}{x^4},$$
hence
$$\theta = \arctan \frac{1}{x^4}.$$
Then the complementary angle is $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$, and its tangent is $\tan \phi = \frac{x^4}{1} = x^4$.  Consequently,
$$\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan \frac{1}{x^4} = \phi = \arctan x^4.$$
The order of the expansion in the denominator must be at least to $x^4$, since the first term is already
$$\arctan x^4 \sim x^4 + O(x^{12}).$$  So your expansion of the numerator must also go out at least this far.  We have
$$\begin{align}
\sin^2 x &= \frac{1 - \cos 2x}{2} \\
&\sim \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - 1 + \frac{(2x)^2}{2!} - \frac{(2x)^4}{4!} + O(x^6)\right) \\
&= x^2 - \frac{x^4}{3} + O(x^6).
\end{align}$$
Also,
$$\begin{align}
\log \cos x
&= - \int \tan x \, dx \\
&\sim - \int \left( x + \frac{x^3}{3} + O(x^5) \right) \, dx \\
&\sim -\frac{x^2}{2} -\frac{x^4}{12} + O(x^6).
\end{align}$$
Thus
$$\frac{a \log \cos x + \sin^2 x}{\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan \frac{1}{x^4}} \sim  \left(1 - \frac{a}{2}\right)x^{-2} - \frac{a+4}{12} + O(x^2).$$